# Is it possible to revert version changes in PaperTrail without overwriting ones that came after?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem, database-versioning

I have a Rails project that has models versioned using the `paper_trail` gem.

I'm looking to have that when I restore a version, I only want to change the fields that were changed in that particular version to be reverted, and not undo the changes of different fields of versions that came after.

For example, say I have a `Person` model with the fields: name, favorite_color and age.

```
# Let's say this doesn't create any version
Person.create(name: 'John', age: 20, favorite_color: 'Green') 

# This creates a version (V1) with the changeset: 20 => 21
Person.update_attributes(age: 21)

# This creates another version (V2) with the changeset: 'Green' => 'Blue'                
Person.update_attributes(favorite_color: 'Blue')

# This creates another version (V3) with the changeset: 'John' => 'James'
# This is also the latest version now
Person.update_attributes(name: 'James')
```

The functionality I'm looking for is if I revert back to V1 so the Person's age goes back to 20, I don't want to undo the changes that came after (i.e. the favorite color change and the name change). So I guess a better way of saying it is I only want to undo that specific field change. (In this case a `Person` with `age: 20`, `favorite_color: 'Blue'` and `name: 'James'`).

I feel like this would be something that PaperTrail already supports. I scanned the docs and the code for something along these lines, searched Google, and looked at past issues, but haven't found anything.

**So my real question is: Did I miss it, or is this just something that PaperTrail doesn't support?**

Until I find out if this is something PaperTrail actually supports, I've extended `PaperTrail::Version` to support this with a function I've called `revert`.

Here's the code if else is interested:

```
# app/models/paper_trail/version.rb

module PaperTrail
  class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PaperTrail::VersionConcern

    def revert
      item = self.item
      item_attributes = {}

      self.changeset.keys.each do |k|
        item_attributes[k] = self.changeset[k][0]
      end

      item.assign_attributes(item_attributes)
      item
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: didn't get it well enough. By reverting you want actually to have some of the fields of that record to be changed and the others stay the same ? So you mean you want to have the reverted record ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @ATF! I added an example for clarification. Hopefully it helps

Comment: Clarified! um as far as I know there is no feature like this in papertrail! You have manage it yourself ! A solution maybe is to find all versions backwards to V1 keep the changes and after reverting to V1 apply those changes !

Comment: The solution I mentioned at the bottom of my post actually seems to be working okay for now. Maybe after doing some testing I'll look into suggesting this as a feature to paper_trail. But thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

When I did:

```rb
some_record.paper_trail.previous_version.save
```

That created a new version with the desired state. It did not overwrite/replace in-between versions.